# In unity facebook sdk, how to avoid "you have already authorized this app" dialog?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

While using facebook sdk in unity after i logged in for the first time. When ever i try to login and play the game again it keeps showing this "you have already authorized this app" dialog. I have click ok there to continue. How can i avoid this?

```
public void Login)
{
    FB.Login("email,public_profile,user_friends");
}
```

That is the piece of code i use to login.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this happens when you are already logged in 
Can you try put it in 
If(FB.IsLoggedIn)? Tell me how does it turn out